# How can I check if a string ends in is or are valid? using regex

Tags: c#, regex

I do a check to see if my strings contain the words "is valid". But how using regex can I check "is valid" or "are valid"?

```
@"Which (of the following )?(is valid) (?<result>.*?)[?:]"
```

Comment: So you want to know if a string ends in the text `is valid` or the text `are valid`?

Comment: Please clarify if you simply looking for the string to contain the substrings or to _end_ with them. Your title and question are a bit at odds with each other.

Comment: Ends in "is valid?" or "are valid?"

Comment: Please clarify _why_ you have to use regex (hint: you can _edit_ your question)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To match both "is valid" and "are valid", you can modify your regular expression like this:

```
@"Which (of the following )?(((is)|(are)) valid) (?<result>.*?)[?:]"
```

Answer (score 2):

This will match `is valid` or `are valid` at the end of a string

`"(is valid)|(are valid)$"`

Comment: Can I just do this with one "valid" and parenthesis around the is / are ?

Comment: @Marianne - true -- I think this is clearer to a new user of regular expressions.

Answer (score 1):

If you have a string of a lot of lines, you can do this:

```
new System.Text.RegularExpressions.Regex("((is)|(are)) valid\n");
```

But it would be an option, split the string into a array of lines (`str.Split('\n')`), and the use `EndsWith` in each line.

Answer (score 0):

What's the problem with `s.Contains("is valid") || s.Contains("are valid")`?

Comment: Because `Contains` will check if a string appears anywhere, and OP wants the match at the end of in input string.